# C hack for storing a bit that takes 1 bit space?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, binary, bit-manipulation

I have a long list of numbers between 0 and 67600. Now I want to store them using an array that is 67600 elements long. An element is set to 1 if a number was in the set and it is set to 0 if the number is not in the set. ie. each time I need only 1bit information for storing the presence of a number. Is there any hack in C/C++ that helps me achieve this?

Comment: If you only need `67600` elements you shouldn't use any trick. It's not that much memory.

Comment: I want minimum possible memory use.

Comment: Use `std::vector<bool>` or `std::bitset`. I wouldn't call them "hacks", though

Comment: @cnicutar if it's for learning experience, a bit trick _should_ be used.

Comment: @NikunjBanka A honorable goal, but with some problem sizes and environments the savings are not worth the effort.

Comment: C or C++? they're different, you know.

Comment: @delnan Not necessarily. It depends on the application. For example, using a `vector<bool>` instead of a `dequeue<bool>` for implementing a large sieve is faster because the task is memory bound.

Comment: You can either use the standard classes already suggested or roll your own with bitwise operations (&, |, ~, ^).

Comment: @Code-Guru can you please explain how I can roll my own implementation using bitwise operators (so that I can employ it in other languages that do not have a vector bool)

Comment: @NikunjBanka It's a wheel that's been invented and reinvented about 65535 times. I bet there are existing implementations online you can look at.

Comment: My comment was to provide some keywords you can use for a google search in case you are unfamiliar with the terminology. After you do some research and have a specific question, I'll be glad to help from there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In C++ you can use `std::vector<bool>` if the size is dynamic (it's a special case of `std::vector`, see [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/)) otherwise there is `std::bitset` (prefer `std::bitset` if possible.) There is also `boost::dynamic_bitset` if you need to set/change the size at runtime. You can find info on it [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html), it is pretty cool!

In C (and C++) you can manually implement this with bitwise operators. A good summary of common operations is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation#Bit_manipulation_in_the_C_programming_language). One thing I want to mention is its a good idea to use unsigned integers when you are doing bit operations. `<<` and `>>` are undefined when shifting negative integers. You will need to allocate arrays of some integral type like `uint32_t`. If you want to store `N` bits, it will take `N/32` of these `uint32_t`s. Bit `i` is stored in the `i % 32`'th bit of the `i / 32`'th `uint32_t`. You may want to use a differently sized integral type depending on your architecture and other constraints. **Note**: prefer using an existing implementation (e.g. as described in the first paragraph for C++, search Google for C solutions) over rolling your own (unless you specifically want to, in which case I suggest learning more about binary/bit manipulation from elsewhere before tackling this.) This kind of thing has been done to death and there are "good" solutions.

There are a number of tricks that will *maybe* only consume one bit: e.g. arrays of bitfields (applicable in C as well), but whether less space gets used is up to compiler. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yszfawxh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Please note that whatever you do, you will almost surely never be able to use **exactly** N bits to store N bits of information - your computer very likely can't allocate less than 8 bits: if you want 7 bits you'll have to waste 1 bit, and if you want 9 you will have to take 16 bits and waste 7 of them. Even if your computer (CPU + RAM etc.) could "operate" on single bits, if you're running in an OS with `malloc`/`new` it would not be sane for your allocator to track data to such a small precision due to overhead. That last qualification was pretty silly - you won't find an architecture in use that allows you to operate on less than 8 bits at a time I imagine :)

Comment: the wikipedia link is great, except that it does not tell me how I would be representing a number of size 2^67600.

Comment: You will need to use more than one integer. If you are using `uint32_t` as your base you will need `NUM_OF_BITS/32` of them and to index you will go to the `i/32`th int and look at its `i%32` bit.

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by uint32_t . Also, if I am thinking right, you seem to cut down the bit usage by a factor of 32. So even in that case 67600/32 = 2113 is very large.

Comment: `stdint.h` in C (`cstdint` in C++) defines `uint32_t` to be an unsigned int that is 4 bytes (32 bits). So each integer will use 32 bits and you need `NUM_OF_BITS/32` of them, for a total storage size of `NUM_OF_BITS` (no space reduction.) If you want to save space that won't be possible in general but if you can make assumptions about what patterns will be in your sets (large contiguous chunks? run length encode it) but that's quite off-topic for this question (make another if you need to)

Comment: here you are : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484669/represent-10000-booleans-using-only-10000-bits

Comment: so, the question was answered here, specific to both languages you asked about and your response was to ask the question again......

Comment: @Nikunj Banka Er, what I meant was that you could use less than N bits to store an N-bit bitset *if* you know some patterns about what bits will be set (this is compression) and meant to start a new question if this is something that interests you... Everyone in here gave the same answer for "How do I store N bits using (approximately) N bits in C/C++".

Answer (score 11):

You should use [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

`std::bitset` functions like an array of `bool` (actually like `std::array`, since it copies by value), but only uses 1 bit of storage for each element.

Another option is `vector<bool>`, which I don't recommend because:

- It uses slower pointer indirection and heap memory to enable resizing, which you don't need.
- That type is often maligned by standards-purists because it claims to be a standard container, but fails to adhere to the definition of a standard container*.

*For example, a standard-conforming function could expect `&container.front()` to produce a pointer to the first element of any container type, which fails with `std::vector<bool>`.  *Perhaps a nitpick for your usage case, but still worth knowing about.*

Comment: Which one is better under which circumstances, `bitset` or `vector<bool>`?

Comment: @JanDvorak: `bitset` if the size is known at compile time (but be careful about putting it on the stack if it's extremely large); `vector<bool>` if it's dynamic.

Comment: Also, Boost has [dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html). Might be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

There is in fact!  `std::vector<bool>` has a specialization for this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool

See the doc, it stores it as efficiently as possible.

Edit: as somebody else said, `std::bitset` is also available: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset

Comment: And everyone now regrets this.

Comment: Ya, reading the doc for it, it really seems "dodgy" to do so.  `std::bitset` seems like the better solution in most cases.  I actually shudder to imagine what case you'd have a dynamic number of bits that need to be queried, as that could be really really weird.

Comment: There is also `boost::dynamic_bitset`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to write it in C, have an array of char that is 67601 bits in length (67601/8 = 8451) and then turn on/off the appropriate bit for each value.

Comment: I have a memory limit of 67600 bits.

Comment: The values are *0 to 67600*, so that's 67601 elements or an array of 8451 chars.

Comment: @NikunjBanka - In which case you can't possibly write this program in any language.

Comment: @Mike - fixed (note that he says he has 67600 bits available, so I'm thinking his problem statement is wrong)

Comment: He said "between 0 and 67600", which doesn't necessarily mean he meant "between 0 and 67600 inclusive"

Comment: see previous "Problem Statement" comment

Answer (score 1):

Others have given the right idea.  Here's my own implementation of a `bitsarr`, or 'array' of bits.  An unsigned char is one byte, so it's essentially an array of unsigned chars that stores information in individual bits.  I added the option of storing TWO or FOUR bit values in addition to ONE bit values, because those both divide 8 (the size of a byte), and would be useful if you want to store a huge number of integers that will range from 0-3 or 0-15.

When setting and getting, the math is done in the functions, so you can just give it an index as if it were a normal array--it knows where to look.

Also, it's the user's responsibility to not pass a value to set that's too large, or it will screw up other values.  It could be modified so that overflow loops back around to 0, but that would just make it more convoluted, so I decided to trust myself.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BYTE 8

typedef enum {ONE=1, TWO=2, FOUR=4} numbits;

typedef struct bitsarr{
    unsigned char* buckets;
    numbits n;
} bitsarr;


bitsarr new_bitsarr(int size, numbits n)
{
    int b = sizeof(unsigned char)*BYTE;
    int numbuckets = (size*n + b - 1)/b;
    bitsarr ret;  
    ret.buckets = malloc(sizeof(ret.buckets)*numbuckets);
    ret.n = n;
    return ret;
}
void bitsarr_delete(bitsarr xp)
{
    free(xp.buckets);
}

void bitsarr_set(bitsarr *xp, int index, int value)
{
    int buckdex, innerdex;
    buckdex = index/(BYTE/xp->n);
    innerdex = index%(BYTE/xp->n);
    xp->buckets[buckdex] = (value << innerdex*xp->n) | ((~(((1 << xp->n) - 1) << innerdex*xp->n)) & xp->buckets[buckdex]);

    //longer version

    /*unsigned int width, width_in_place, zeros, old, newbits, new;
    width = (1 << xp->n) - 1; 
    width_in_place = width << innerdex*xp->n;
    zeros = ~width_in_place;
    old = xp->buckets[buckdex];
    old = old & zeros;
    newbits = value << innerdex*xp->n;
    new = newbits | old;
    xp->buckets[buckdex] = new; */

}

int bitsarr_get(bitsarr *xp, int index)
{
    int buckdex, innerdex;
    buckdex = index/(BYTE/xp->n);
    innerdex = index%(BYTE/xp->n);
    return ((((1 << xp->n) - 1) << innerdex*xp->n) & (xp->buckets[buckdex])) >> innerdex*xp->n;

    //longer version

    /*unsigned int width = (1 << xp->n) - 1; 
    unsigned int width_in_place = width << innerdex*xp->n;
    unsigned int val = xp->buckets[buckdex];
    unsigned int retshifted = width_in_place & val;
    unsigned int ret = retshifted >> innerdex*xp->n;
    return ret; */
}

int main()
{
    bitsarr x = new_bitsarr(100, FOUR);
    for(int i = 0; i<16; i++)
        bitsarr_set(&x, i, i);
    for(int i = 0; i<16; i++)
        printf("%d\n", bitsarr_get(&x, i));
    for(int i = 0; i<16; i++)
        bitsarr_set(&x, i, 15-i);
    for(int i = 0; i<16; i++)
        printf("%d\n", bitsarr_get(&x, i));
    bitsarr_delete(x);
}
```